# selector for first sibling with id starting with

Tags: jquery, insert, selector

Having trouble finding the correct selector/jquery code for the following scenario. Want to from the starting point of a tr with id starting with SIEcat insert new row before the next row starting with SIEcat?

```html
<table>
  <tr id="SIEcat1"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr id="SIEcat2"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
</table>
```

etc

Code so far

```
$("#SIEcat1").selectorcodeXXX.before('<tr class="SIErow">xxxx</tr>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of CSS attribute starts-with and jQuery's nextAll() selector:

`$('[id^=SIEcat]').nextAll('[id^=SIEcat]').before('<tr class="SIErow"><td>xxxx</td></tr>');`

This selects the element with an id starting with SIEcat, then iterates through all the following siblings until it finds the next id starting with SIEcat and inserts the row before it.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOXWxe).

Comment: and add .first() to just select the first occurrence?

Comment: @KevinLindmark You mean to insert the row before only the first SIEcat that follows the initial SIEcat? If so, yes, like this `$('[id^=SIEcat]').nextAll('[id^=SIEcat]').first().before('<tr class="SIErow"><td>xxxx</td></tr>');` Here's a codepen example with multiple SIEcat rows and the new row only inserting before the first repetition: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEvPqd

Answer (score 0):

You can use "start with" selector: `^=` and [`first`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) method, 
like this: `$('[id^=SIEcat]').first()`

```js
$('[id^=SIEcat]').first().before('<tr class="SIErow"><td>xxxx</td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="SIEcat1"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr id="SIEcat2"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use following selector:

```js
$('[id^=SIEcat]:not(:first-child)').before('<tr class="SIErow"><td>xxxx</td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="SIEcat1"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr id="SIEcat2"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
  <tr class="SIErow"><td>Columncode</td></tr>
</table>
```